# How to use a manual UITabbar and use it to switch through other ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I created a manual UITabbar and I created 3 TabBarItems that I want to use to switch through other Viewcontrollers. I can't find a way to use the BarItems to switch through other Viewcontrollers throughout the app. Is there a way to switch through Viewcontroller programmatically? I am using Swift.

Here is a look at my ViewController.swift file...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    // All Outlets Connected to StoryBoard
    @IBOutlet var BTN: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BTN2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BTN3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BTN4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var tbl: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var Button: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var AllButton: UITabBarItem!//First Item
    @IBOutlet var TabBar1: UITabBar! //Manual UITabbar
    @IBOutlet var PriorityButton: UITabBarItem!//Third Item
    @IBOutlet var ClassesButton: UITabBarItem!//Second Item
    @IBOutlet var Bar: UINavigationItem!

    //Other Variables
    var varView = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if revealViewController() != nil {
            Button.target = revealViewController()
            Button.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        }

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 50 / 255.0, green: 132 / 255.0, blue: 255 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        BTN.alpha = 1.0
        BTN4.alpha = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func BTNClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: ({
            self.BTN2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -90)
            self.BTN3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -180)
            self.BTN4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0)
            self.BTN.alpha = 0
            self.BTN4.alpha = 1.0
        }))
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        //This method will be called when user changes tab.

        //Do I use this? I am using a manual Tabbar just to remind you guys.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITabBar` just displays a tab bar and tells its delegate when the user chooses a different tab. [`UITabBarController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/) does exactly what you seem to want: it manages a collection of view controllers, switching between them as the user selects different tabs. There's nothing magical or unprogrammatic about using `UITabBarController` -- if you don't want to use storyboards you can always configure a `UITabBarController` in code. Unless there's something you're not telling us, you should use `UITabBarController`.

If you really want to use just `UITabBar`, you can implement [`UITabBarDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006930) in your view controller and set the view controller as the tab bar's delegate. When the user taps on a tab, your `-tabBar:didSelectItem:` method will be called and you can do whatever you want, including switch to a different view. The tab bar won't do the switching for you -- `UITabBar` is *just* the tab bar view, without any logic for managing views or view controllers.

The title of your question says that you want to switch between view *controllers*, not just views. But you probably want the tab bar to be visible at all times. That means that you'll need to create a view controller that maintains a list of view controllers associated with tab items, has a child view controller, and implements `UITabBarDelegate` such that it replaces the child view controller whenever `-tabBar:didSelectItem:` is called. In short, you'll need to duplicate what `UITabBarController` already does.

Comment: Is there a way to just use the Tabbar to switch through views, not the UITabBarController?

Comment: @Caleb So Im using the `-tabBar:didSelectItem:` method you mentioned to "Push" segue to another ViewController. Problem is that it leaves an empty space where the TabBar was in the original VC. How can I have the Tabbar appear when i segue to different VC's?

Comment: @brkr **Use `UITabBarController` instead.** If the tab bar is part of the view hierarchy managed by the view controller that you're switching away from, it's no surprise that the tab bar disappears when you switch, right? So, you have to manage that yourself, or use something that manages it for you. The latter approach is far superior, and that thing is `UITabBarController`. Is there some reason you've chosen not to use it? Using it is far, far less complicated than using `UITabBar` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add a UITabBar to a controller without using a UITabBarController, try the below class. It's only bare bones and shows only what you really need. This example assumes that you added a UITabBar to your controller in the storyboard, as shown by the @IBOutlet. I personally tried this and it works great.

```
public class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var tabBar: UITabBar!

  public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar?.delegate = self // this is the important step!
  }

  public func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("selected")
  }
}
```